# Change Font Size in R Shiny Input Options (shinyjqui)

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make the font size of the words on each button to be smaller (which would hopefully also shrink the overall button size for each option) but am struggling to find the right place to write the **style = 'font-size: 5px'** code. Where would I add that?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$order <- renderPrint({ print(input$dest) })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  orderInput('source', 'Source', items = month.abb,
             as_source = TRUE, connect = 'dest'),
  orderInput('dest', 'Dest', items = NULL, placeholder = 'Drag items here...'),
  verbatimTextOutput('order')
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$order <- renderPrint({ print(input$dest) })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    orderInput('source', 'Source', items = month.abb,
               as_source = TRUE, connect = 'dest'),
    orderInput('dest', 'Dest', items = NULL, placeholder = 'Drag items here...'),
    verbatimTextOutput('order'),
    tags$style(HTML(
        '
        .btn.shinyjqui {font-size: 5px}
        '
    ))
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

##### to also shrink the button

```r
    tags$style(HTML(
        '
        .btn.shinyjqui {
            font-size: 5px;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        '
    ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to correspondingly shrink the button itself to fit the new text size?

Comment: @Justin see edits, but you sure this is you want? too small to see lol

Comment: That's perfect. I just chose 5px randomly haha